# Fill new table from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

1. questions
2. tags
3. questions_tags -> pivot table (many to many relation)

I need to create new table called "tags_languages" and fill it with tag's languages based on question's language (many to many relation) from "questions" and "tags" tables

tables structure:

"questions" table

```
id     text     language_id
1     What..        1
2     How...        1
3     Is...         2
4     Is...         2
5     Where..       3
```

"tags" table

```
id     text
1      London
2      England
3      ball
4      love
5      yellow
```

"questions_tags" table

```
id     question_id     tag_id
1          1              1
2          1              2
3          2              1
4          2              2
5          2              3
6          1              3
7          3              2
8          2              4
9          1              4
10         4              3
```

required table:

"tags_languages": (tag_id & language_id) -> composite primary key

```
tag_id     language_id
  1             1
  2             1
  2             2
  3             1
  3             2
  4             1
```

thanks,

Comment: I left unedited your usage of `pivot table` because it does make sense in some ways, but be careful because nowadays `pivot` usually means a very specific thing in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

This generates the output you mention:

```
SELECT  qt.tag_id, q.language_id
    FROM  questions q
    JOIN  questions_tags qt ON qt.question_id = q.id;
```

It is "wrong" to put that into a table since you can always reconstruct it on the fly.  (Redundant data in a database is a no-no.)

Sticking this in front of the SELECT will create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE tags_languages (
    PRIMARY KEY(tag_id, language_id) )
```

"Many-to-many" and "pivot" are not synonyms.

Perhaps your real goal is something beyond "I need to create new table".  Would you care to discuss that?

Comment: yes, I can construct it on the fly, but both "questions" & "questions_tags" tables are very big and frequently updated, "on the fly" query have very bad performance in my tests

Comment: @mwafi then the structure of your query/table is to be reviewed. For such tables, millions or records is a small amount of rows and mysql buffer would just do great about it.

Comment: If you are worried about performance, then let's look at the SELECTs and the CREATE TABLEs.  A `BIGINT` where a `MEDIUMINT` would do will waste 5 bytes per row.  Bulkiness slows things down.  Etc.